# SYCL q.memcpy() & h.memcpy() & Intel developer cloud problems

Tags: memcpy, sycl, dpc++

I'm using SYCL on Intel Develope Cloud to test Innovative algorithms.

My questions:

1. SYCL `q.memcpy()` & `h.memcpy()` do not work. It seems that [Intel
   know about it](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Base-Toolkit/sycl-queue-memcpy-sycl-handler-memcpy-with-std-string-view-and/m-p/1258765)

   What is the status of this issue? And most importantly, is there another way to transfer data explicitly when using USM and `malloc_device`?
2. Lately I've been getting the message "The server is unavailable or unreachable" when I use Intel developer cloud, every two minutes. It wasn't like that until a week ago. What could be the reasons?
3. How can I tell what is the DPC++ compiler version when I'm working with Intel developer cloud?

Comment: Questions about the server outages at Intel are off-topic on SO. A question about the status of some issue in an Intel forum should probably be posted in that forum under that issue. Generally SO questions should contain a single question each, not three. Most compilers will tell you their version if you pass them the `--version` flag.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your query has been handled in the Intel community forum.
Please refer to the below link for your reference,
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Developer-Cloud/SYCL-q-memcpy-amp-h-memcpy-amp-Intel-developer-cloud-problems/m-p/1547439